Solana Rent Calculation
Could someone please provide guidance or a code example on how to calculate rent for Solana accounts? Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how to determine the rent due for each account based on its balance, state, and other relevant parameters.
Any insights, explanations, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!
